# Optimized write to FS in Python

Tags: python

My Python program is pretty slow because it dumps many lines to a log file. Is there a faster way to do this? I thought of defining a buffer, so that only when it is filled up (or when the file is closed) a file system write will be executed?
Is there a library API that does this?

To be more specific instead off the following code:

```
fd = open(data_file, 'w')
fd.write(line1) # a FS write
fd.write(line2) # a FS write
.
.
.
fd.write(line100) # a FS write

# ==> a total of 100 FS writes
```

I would like to use something like:

```
fd = open(data_file, 'w')
fd.define_buff_size(100 * size_of_line) # this is the API I am looking for...
fd.write(line1) # no FS write
fd.write(line2) # a FS write
.
.
.
fd.write(line100) # The 1st FS write

# ==>a total of 1 FS write
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think your first example issues 100 writes? In fact I would expect it not to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The open function in python allows you to set the buffer size. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

```
fd = open (data_file, 'w', 100 * size_of_line)
```

Comment: Note that the `buffer` size is in *bytes*, not *lines*.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file in the first place you can define the buffer mode/size

```
file object = open(file_name [, access_mode][, buffering])
```

file_name: The file_name argument is a string value that contains the name of the file that you want to access.

access_mode: The access_mode determines the mode in which the file has to be opened, i.e., read, write, append, etc. A complete list of possible values is given below in the table. This is optional parameter and the default file access mode is read (r).

buffering: If the buffering value is set to 0, no buffering will take place. If the buffering value is 1, line buffering will be performed while accessing a file. If you specify the buffering value as an integer greater than 1, then buffering action will be performed with the indicated buffer size. If negative, the buffer size is the system default(default behavior).

[see here for more info](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

James